# Editable resolves to undefined mixing KnockOutJS and plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, undefined

I tried to create a drop-down menu using options binding in KnockOut JS (ko.plus to be precise). Things were running as expected until I mixed my solution up with this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jnuc6y05/ in order to place a default option in the list. The problem lies in "HERE" (please see the code) where I get
error message

> "TypeError: this.fieldStreetApallou is not a function"

As I said I had no problem, and I think mixing plain javascript with KO caused the situation. I tried to unwrap the editable with no luck since it resolves to undefined. Even ko.toJS does not do the trick (undefined again).

I don't have any serious experience with KO and furthermore with Javascript, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: Reduced code provided

```
/////// HTML

    <input data-bind="value: fieldStreetApallou, enable: fieldStreetApallou.isEditing" />
        <a href="#" data-bind="visible: !fieldStreetApallou.isEditing(), click: fieldStreetApallou.beginEdit">Rename</a>
    <div data-bind="visible: fieldStreetApallou.isEditing">
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: function() { fieldStreetApallou.endEdit(); postStreetFieldToServerForApallou(); }"> Confirm</a>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: fieldStreetApallou.cancelEdit"> Cancel</a>
    </div>

    /////// Javascript
    <script type="text/javascript">

        ko.observableArray.fn.find = function(prop, data) {
            var valueToMatch = data[prop];
            return ko.utils.arrayFirst(this(), function(item) {
                return item[prop] === valueToMatch;
            });
        };

        var availableCompanies = [{
            offset: 1,
            name: "Company1"
        }, {
            offset: 2,
            name: "Company2"
        }
         // ...more pairs here
        ];


        //Default pairs for the drop-down menus
        var selectedCompanyApallou = {
            offset: 1,
            name: "Company1"
        };

        var ViewModel = function(availableCompanies, selectedCompanyApallou) {
            this.availableCompaniesApallou = ko.observableArray(availableCompanies);
            this.selectedCompanyApallou = ko.observable(this.availableCompaniesApallou.find("offset", selectedCompanyApallou));

            this.fieldStreetApallou = ko.editable("Initial value");

            postStreetFieldToServerForApallou = function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "PUT",
                    url: "http://www.san-soft.com/goandwin/addresses/" + 15,
                    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
                    data: "Address_id=15&Street=" + this.fieldStreetApallou() //<---- HERE!
                }).done(function(data) {
                    alert("Record Updated Successfully " + data.status);
                }).fail(function(err) {
                    alert("Error Occured, Please Reload the Page and Try Again " + err.status);
                });
            };

        };

        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(availableCompanies, selectedCompanyApallou));

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you linked to the wrong JSFiddle.

Looks like `this` is not what you are expecting when `postStreetFieldToServerForApallou` is called by the button click. `this` in JavaScript is based on who called the function.

To work around it in this case, I like to set `var self = this;` at the top of the view model so `self` always points to the view model, then I replace all instances of `this` with `self`.  This is really only needed on your HERE line, but it simplifies to use `self` throughout.

The fixed view model code:

```
var ViewModel = function(availableCompanies, selectedCompanyApallou) {
    var self = this;
    self.availableCompaniesApallou = ko.observableArray(availableCompanies);
    self.selectedCompanyApallou = ko.observable(self.availableCompaniesApallou.find("offset", selectedCompanyApallou));

    self.fieldStreetApallou = ko.editable("Initial value");

    postStreetFieldToServerForApallou = function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            url: "http://www.san-soft.com/goandwin/addresses/" + 15,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
            data: "Address_id=15&Street=" + self.fieldStreetApallou() //<---- HERE!
        }).done(function(data) {
            alert("Record Updated Successfully " + data.status);
        }).fail(function(err) {
            alert("Error Occured, Please Reload the Page and Try Again " + err.status);
        });
    };
};
```